# Cannot make new directories in FTP (C#)

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, ftp, windows

I was trying to upload a file to my FTP server (EC2) via a simple C# windows application I made.

Problem I'm Having :  If the directory already exists, I can make a file inside it. However, if the directory doesn't exist, I cannot  make a directory.

What I Checked : I double checked the write permissions. I logged in via WinSCP and I can make new directories in there without any problems. I've given the user privileges.

My Code :

```
private async void FileFTPUpload(string sourcefilepath, string folderPath) {
 String ftpurl = @"ftp://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/" + "trial/12/1.txt";
 Console.WriteLine("Ftp url : " + ftpurl);
 String ftpusername = "myUserName";
 String ftppassword = "myPassword";

 try {
  string filename = Path.GetFileName(sourcefilepath);
  string ftpfullpath = ftpurl;
  WebRequest ftp = WebRequest.Create(ftpurl);
  ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
  ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);

  ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

  FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(sourcefilepath);
  byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
  fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  fs.Close();

  Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
  ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  ftpstream.Close();
 } catch (Exception ex) {
  Console.WriteLine("Exception Occurred : " + ex);
  //throw ex;
 }
}
```

Now, if the "trial/12/" exists, then 1.txt will be made. Otherwise, I get the error :

`System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (553) File name not allowed.`

I'm not sure what's happening and what's not. Could use some assistance.

Thank You.

EDIT : When I do this :
    String ftpurl = @"ftp://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/" + "trial";

It doesn't make a directory. I just makes a file named "trial".

Doing This :

```
String ftpurl = @"ftp://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/" + "trial/";
```

Gives that same error 553

Comment: You set `ftp.Method` two times. The first assigment is therefore never used. This won't work you need to seperate your code into two requests.

Comment: I've updated my question. Please take a look at that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to seperate your code into two requests. The first should create the directory and the second upload the file.

```
var filePath = @"ftp://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/trial/12/1.txt";
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);

{
    // create directory
    var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
    var request = WebRequest.Create(directoryPath);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
    request.Credentials = credentials;
    using(var response = (FtpWebResponse)requestDir.GetResponse()) 
    {
        // TODO: handle errors
    }
}

{
    // upload file
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Credentials = credentials;
        client.UploadFile(filePath, "STOR", sourcefilepath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It worked. Just had to change a few things. Source file path. great! :)